# Get query string value from parameter that contains [ ]

Tags: php

I need to get values from a query string but this is a special condition. I have the following url:

```
domain.com?custom_field[email]=test@test.net
```

But I get the url in this format

```
domain.com?custom_field%5Bemail%5D=test@test.net
```

I tried using generic `$_GET['custom_field[email]'];` but its not working.

I also tried:

```
urldecode($_GET['custom_field[email]']);
```

But its not working either. Can anyone please tip me how can I get solution for this.

Comment: `[]` in a field name like that is a notice to PHP to create an array of values for that field, you'd have `$_GET['custom_field]['email']` (note the extra array dimension). And in any case, `var_dump($_GET)` would show you EXACTLY what php parsed that query string into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your form looks like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="email" name="custom_field[email]"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

and you submit `test@example.com`, then your url will look like this:

http://localhost/file.php?custom_field%5Bemail%5D=test%40example.com

you can see what the data looks like with:

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
```

which will display:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [custom_field] => Array
>         (
>             [email] => test@example.com
>         )
>
> )
> ```

so you can specifically reference the entity with:

```
echo $_GET['custom_field']['email'];
```

Comment: In case the input is named like that, it's worth checking if it really should be named with such 'complexity'...